# Min Width not working in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small issues (i hope it's small) with my mini shopping cart layout, i'm using bootstrap 3,

**Working (IE & FireFox)**

working in ie and firefox example:

[image]

**Not Working (Chrome)**

not working in chrome example:

[image]

In IE and firefox the cart dropdown displays great, but in chrome the text is all squashed up, it doesn't seem to work using: **min-width: 350px;** in the .css file.

**CSS Code:**

```
.product_view .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}
.pre-cost {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}
.space-ten {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
ul.dropdown-cart {
    min-width: 350px;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin: 3px 0;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item:hover {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left {
    float: left;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left img,
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info {
    float: left;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info span {
    display: block;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-right {
    float: right;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-right button {
    margin-top: 14px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">

      <?php if (empty($_SESSION['member']) || !isset($_SESSION['member']) || !isset($member)) { ?>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> HOME</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>shop.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> SHOP <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                       <li><?php $c = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `categories`"); foreach($c as $cat) { echo "<a href=\"shop.php?catId={$cat['cat_id']}\">{$cat['cat_name']}</a>"; } ?></li>

                     </ul>
                </li>               
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> SIGNUP</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> LOGIN</a></li>
          </ul>

          <?php } else { ?>

           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> HOME</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>shop.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> SHOP <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                       <li><?php $c = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `categories`"); $url = getUrl(); foreach($c as $cat) { echo "<a href=\"{$url}shop.php?catId={$cat['cat_id']}\">{$cat['cat_name']}</a>"; } ?></li>

                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>my-account.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>my-orders.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> MY ORDERS</a></li>
           </ul>      

      <?php } ?>

      <!-- Search -->
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>" method="get">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search store ..." name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> CART <b><span class="label label-badge label-danger"><?php echo (addUpProductInCart($member) > 0) ? addUpProductInCart($member) : "0"; ?></span></b><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">

              <?php $cart = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `cart_customer_id`='{$member}' AND `cart_payment_processed`='N'"); ?>

              <?php foreach ($cart as $cartProduct) { ?>

              <li>  
                  <span class="item">
                    <span class="item-left">
                        <img src="<?php echo $cartProduct['cart_thumbnail']; ?>" style="width:50px; height:50px;" alt="" />
                        <span class="item-info">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo strtolower($truncated = (strlen($cartProduct['cart_product_name']) > 20) ? substr($cartProduct['cart_product_name'], 0, 35) . '...' : $cartProduct['cart_product_name']); ?></span>
                            <span class="text-success">&dollar;<?php echo $cartProduct['cart_product_price']; ?></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
              </li>

              <?php } ?>

              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a class="text-center" href="<?php echo getUrl(); ?>cart.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View Cart</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I'm not exactly sure what i could add to fix, i never posted any of the cart code, i can post it if anyone thinks it would be helpful, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Thank you Obsidian, just updated my question with the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be targeting the wrong css as bootstrap will have different css for different media queries

for a quick fix with out live view of the code try

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu" style="width:350px">
```

where

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu">
```

Comment: Thank you ukjnr1 that did work, i'll use that :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming it’s because you don’t have this on your html
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`